# How to create a new table after reaching a height in xsl?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have xml file like:

```
<lines>
   <line>
       <id>1</id>
       <value>1</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>2</id>
       <value>2</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>3</id>
       <value>3</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>4</id>
       <value>4</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>5</id>
       <value>5</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>6</id>
       <value>6</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>7</id>
       <value>7</value> 
   </line>
   <line>
       <id>8</id>
       <value>8</value> 
   </line>
<lines>
```

and my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="lines/line">
    <tr>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

My question is, how can I divide this xml nodes due to a table height?
For example, after table reaches 100px, then close table tag and create new table and add tr tag to this new table?

How can I succeed this? I tried for row count but sometimes text in xml can be very large. So, I want to descrease row count in table.

Any help?

Comment: How do you want to measure a tables height? After it is rendered by a browser? If a css-statement state: tr {height:25px;}, you have to quit after 4 rows? My one and only idea would be a transform in javascript and measure after adding row for row. But totally inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to this kind of requirement is to write a recursive template that takes as parameters (a) the "height reached so far", and (b) the "maximum height". The template should process one row, then test whether the maximum height has been reached; if so it should return, otherwise it should call itself to process the next row, passing a new value for the "height reached so far" parameter.

(You can reduce it to a single parameter if you count down to zero rather than up to some limit.)